# What online modes are available in Team Sonic Racing?

Tags: team-sonic-racing

I'm considering purchasing Team Sonic Racing on steam. I'm curious what online modes it offers. Going through youtube, all I ever see are one-off casual races. Is there an online grand prix mode?

Can someone who owns the game please make a list of the customization for the online mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to preface this answer by letting you know that, despite the game only being one month old at the time of writing, the online community is already dead. Online matchmaking was plagued by bugs at launch. If you are looking to use the matchmaking system to get a game going, you might be able to find 1 or 2 other human players at best.

---

If you want to play Team Sonic Racing online, you can find a game with the matchmaking system, or you can create/join a custom game. Custom games can only be joined by invitation.

## Custom Game Options

*Race Type:*

- Standard (Race solo)
- Team (Race as a team of 3)

*Race Difficulty:*

- Normal
- Hard
- Expert

*Max AI:*

- 0 to 11

*Rules:*

- Regular
- Lightning Race (Activate invincibility at the right time to avoid lightning strikes)
- King of the Hill (Gain points by staying in 1st place)
- Vampire Race (Collect coins and steal them from your opponents for a speed increase)
- Rocket Race (Item boxes only contain rockets)
- Boost Race (Item boxes only contain boosts)
- Grand Prix (Play 1 of 6 sets of 4 races)

*Mirrored Tracks:*

- Enabled
- Disabled

## Matchmaking

The matchmaking system will pair you with other players in either a casual or ranked standard race, or a casual or ranked team race. Once you join a lobby you can vote on the race you would like to play from a pool of 4 randomly generated races.

I'm not sure if all of the special game types are available in matchmaking, but in the 10 or so games I played I did get vampire race twice. So at the very least I can confirm that you are not restricted to regular races in matchmaking. However, it is clear from the format that grand prix is not an available game mode in matchmaking.