# Can I play multiplayer Team Sonic Racing across platforms?

Tags: team-sonic-racing

One of my friends has Team Sonic Racing for PlayStation 4. If I buy the game for Nintendo Switch, can I play online with him or does the multiplayer only work for users on the same console (e.g. PlayStation 4 users can only play with other PlayStation 4 users)?

I found [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/353331/161932) question, but it does not address the multi-platform aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Team Sonic Racing does not support cross-play, which means you can not play Team Sonic Racing across other platforms.

---

This was confirmed in an interview with Takashi Iizuka, the lead producer and current Vice President of Product Development for the Sonic the Hedgehog series at Sega.

> ***Interviewee:*** "Will you be supporting cross-platform play? Because it's on four platforms, correct? So will you be able to matchmake with
> people across platforms?"
>
> ***Takashi Iizuka:*** "Since we're not quite at the point where we can get all platforms to play together in one unique universe, we're kind
> of moving away from focusing on getting that on cross-platform play." 
> **[Team Sonic Racing - Developer Interview](https://youtu.be/UtwYEGZt3lQ?t=172)**